# Remove storyboard UISearchBar in a UITableView and add it in an other tableview programmatically

Tags: ios, objective-c, uitableview, storyboard, uisearchbar

I am working on a project right now and I have to change the old code and using what have been done,

I am collecting information (`item, label ..`) by parsing Json,
in the old code we have a modal view that is divided in two parts :the first part display a picture of the Item and the second is a table-view with multiple button and a search bar,
what I have to do is to split that,

I need to have the search bar in a an other table view that I push by click on a button, when I click on a search-bar it push an other view controller which display a map,
the problem is what have been done used a storyboard and I have to do it programmatically!
How can I do it?

Comment: As far as I understand... you don't want a UISearchBar on one view, instead you want it on some other view. correct?

Comment: Yes exactlly, but the problem is the UIserachBar that already exists was implemented using a storyboard , and when i try to remove it i have a lot of problems and the application don't work anymore !!

Comment: Why can't you use storyboard?? just go ahead and create a new controller and drag your uiserachbar on that controller.

Comment: I can't i have to use just the previous code and do it programmaticlly !

Answer (score 0):

You can remove UISearchBar programmatically by sending removeFromSuperview message to it, and then go ahead and create a new instance of it and place it accordingly.

Answer (score 0):

You can set the UISearchBar as the header of a tableView in a very simple way.
For eg. define your search bar like this

```
self.searchBar = [[UISearchBar alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0, 0, self.view.frame.size.width, 44)];
self.searchBar.barTintColor = weAskDefaultBkgColor;
self.searchBar.placeholder = @"Search users by their name or username";
self.searchBar.delegate = self;
```

Then, set this as tableView header

```
- (UIView *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView viewForHeaderInSection:(NSInteger)section{
  return self.searchBar;
}
```